# How to find a variable that is causing scope colision?

Tags: javascript, html, scope, frontend

i just started a new html project as any other day, but totay i was suprised with scope colision in javascript. The point is i'm trying to declare a variable called top, but i think that i had already declared it in another file and i would like to know if there is a fast way to find this file and fix it.

This is my html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>day one</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>hiii</h1>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is my javascript:

```js
let top = [0, 0, 0]
```

When i open the devtools and look at the console there is an error message there: `script.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'top' has already been declared (at script.js:1:1)`

So i tried to `console.log()` the top variable and the output was the window

```js
console.log(top)
// same thing as
console.log(window)
```

So i think that the best approach is trying to find original file where the `top`  variable is, any ideas?

I don't know what to do ;-; HELP PLEASEEEE

Answer (score 1):

`top` is a built in global property of the window. So you can't use it as a variable name when running in the browser:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/top.

Comment: No, i'm not running this in the browser and i'm not trying to use the window.top .
   top is the name of the variable that i'm trying to create, but for some reason colision scoping is happening and my js code i'ts ecxactly as my first example

Comment: You are running it in the browser - if you're running HTML it's running in the browser. That's how websites work, the browser is the engine that renders HTML and executes Javascript. Something in a 'script' tag never runs server side. 

The collision scoping is occurring because `top` is a global variable that is predefined. You can't redefine a global variable. Your only option is to rename your variable. You can't name a variable the same thing as a property of the global object (e.g. window)